# Guide for creating a navigation on google maps

Tags: waze

I'm working on a app right now. I'd like to know if you have a guide on navigation, like the marker is moving on the road and trail a drawing of line. It's like the opposite of what waze is doing when navigating, the marker is following the drawing of line.

I already done the basics of google maps api, creating a flag, drawing a direction from point a to b and etc.

Thank you for the help! :)